# Recalculate width of dragged element with jQuery UI draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I need to dynamically change the width of a `<div>` if it is dragged out of its parent element so its right edge stays "glued" to the parent's right edge and the contents of a `<div>` wrap inside the new width. After days of googling and reading posts here I've managed to resize the `<div>` once when it touches the parent. I tried mouseup/mousedown to restart it but it doesn't work.

The end result should work both ways (return to its original size when dragged back into the parent), something like resizing the `<div>` from the left edge while it's floated to the right. But for now, I at least want it to resize dynamically as I'm dragging it "out of" the parent.

I'm sure I've seen this somewhere and I refuse to believe it's impossible.

```js
let item = $( '#item' );
let draggableRight;
let parentWidth = $('#parent').outerWidth();

function resizeMe() {
  draggableRight = item.position().left + item.width();
  if (draggableRight > parentWidth) {
    item.width(item.width() - 50);
  }
}

item.draggable({
  scroll: false,
  containment: 'parent',
  drag: function (event, ui) {
    resizeMe();
  }
});
```

```css
#parent {
  height: 100vh;
}

#item {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="item">
    <span>Some random text</span>
    <p>I want this to continue wrapping/shrinking as I'm dragging to the right.</p>
  </div>
</div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```